# MySQL Conditional Join

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

As you can see below, I am checking to see if the current user is in `user_a` or `user_b` columns of table **friends**.

Depending on where the current user is located, I want to get his corresponding friend.

Somehow I can't get this syntax to work and wonder if anyone can tell me what's wrong (I get an error on line 3 near `IF user_a = 2`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM friends
IF user_a = 2 THEN
  JOIN user_profiles ON friends.user_b = user.profiles.user_id
 WHERE user_a = 2
   AND accepted = 1;
ELSEIF user_b = 2 THEN
  JOIN user_profiles ON friends.user_a = user_profiles.user_id
 WHERE user_b = 2
   AND accepted = 1;
END IF;
```

Comment: OK it seems there's a consensus that this is some crapshot mySQL code -- does anyone have a suggestion / roadmap for me to achieve the result I want?

Comment: If you explain what you're actually trying to accomplish, it would be easier to help.

Comment: You can do it with a UNION...see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a UNION:

```
select f.*, up_a.* from friends f
  inner join user_profiles up_a on f.user_a=up_a.user_id
  where f.user_b=2 and f.accepted=1
union
select f.*, up_b.* from friends f
  inner join user_profiles up_b on f.user_b=up_b.user_id
  where f.user_a=2 and f.accepted=1;
```

Comment: @AJ - nice, this works well -- @AJ could you edit your response to add `AND accepted = 1` in lines 3 and 7? that fullfils my original question and allows my query to filter out friendships that are still pending (ie, accepted = 0) - thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You are inventing syntax.  The "IF" in MySQL is supported as:

1. Statement, for use in stored procedures and triggers.  Docs: 
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html
2. Function, for use in choosing one of alternate expressions for a result column.  Docs:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

You appear to be doing something else entirely.

Comment: thx @dkamins, let me know if you have an alternative to get this query

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you're attempting to use is unsupported.  I don't think you can use an `IF` conditional to branch your SQL  statement in this manner.  It may be possible to fit this into a `SELECT CASE`.

If you can use local variables, something along these lines may work:

```
BEGIN
SELECT user_a, user_b INTO local_a, local_b FROM friends;

IF local_a = 2 THEN
  SELECT * FROM friends JOIN user_profiles ON friends.user_b = users.profiles.user_id
  WHERE user_a = 2 AND accepted = 1;
ELSEIF user_b = 2 THEN
  SELECT * FROM friends JOIN user_profiles ON friends.user_b = users.profiles.user_id
  WHERE user_b = 2 AND accepted = 1
END IF;
END;
```

I'm not certain of the validity of this either, but it may send you down the right road.  See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into-statement.html

Comment: do you mean using `IF` with `JOIN` and `WHERE` inside?

Comment: @torr Yes I mean using `IF` in any place inside a `SELECT` statement and expecting it to construct a full valid SQL statement dynamically.